# Como puedo descargar un archivo de un servidor y guardarlo en local c#

Tags: c#, web, archivo, descarga

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una aplicación web alojada en un servidor, esta aplicación web debe permitir la descarga de ciertos ficheros alojados en ese mismo servidor.
Como puedo realizar esto desde código sin FTP?

Comment: Por favor leer [ask]. Tupregunta carece de muchos detalles y hasta se basa en opiniones. ¿Qué has intentado / averiguado? Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear en tu controlador

```
public FileResult Getfile(string downloadFileName)
    {

        string nombrearchivo= Path.GetFileName(nombrearchivo).Trim();
        byte[] fl = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/carpeta/" + nombrearchivo));
        return File(fl, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, nombreDocumento);
    }
```

después llamarlo con js

```
function DescargarArchivo(nombrearchivo) {
window.open("Getfile?downloadFileName=" + rutaDocumento , "Cliente" );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.cualquiercosa.com/images/";
string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);
```

eso debiera descargar el gif a la carpeta local